# What is causing this Error: com.android.tools.r8.internal.nc: Sealed classes are not supported as program classes

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Jetpack Compose, and while learning I ran into some problems that I don't know how to solve. Below is my development environment, code and compiled result.

**Environment:**

- Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2Build
- Kotlin version: 1.7.10
- Android Gradle version: 7.2.2
- JDK version: 17.0.4
- CompileSdk: 33

**Code:**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DemoTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Greeting(
    viewModel: GreetingViewModel = remember {
        GreetingViewModel()
    }
) {
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(32.dp)
    ) {
        TextField(value = uiState.name, onValueChange = {

            viewModel.handleAction(
                GreetingViewModel.UiAction.NameChanged(it)
            )
        })
        Text(text = "Hello ${uiState.name}!")
    }
}
```

```
class GreetingViewModel {
    data class UiState(val name: String)

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState(name = ""))
    val uiState: StateFlow<UiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    sealed class UiAction {
        class NameChanged(val name: String) : UiAction()
    }

    fun handleAction(action: UiAction) {
        when (action) {
            is UiAction.NameChanged -> {
                _uiState.value = uiState.value.copy(
                    name = action.name
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
GreetingViewModel$UiAcion.class: Decompiled.class file, bytecode version:61.0(Java 17)

Waring: One or more classes has class file version >= 56 which is not officially supported.

Error: com.android.tools.r8.internal.nc: Sealed classes are not supported as program classes
```

Comment: and check Kotlin sdk version , it must b updated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is due to building using JDK 17 and not telling it to make things Android-compatible (ie. Java 11). When building Java / Kotlin classes for Android, you need to produce Java 11-compatible bytecode. You can still use JDK 17 to build but you need to tell it to dial it back a little and not use new stuff that the dexer won't be able to handle.

You can do that in your build file like so (assuming KTS build files here, the tasks.withType syntax is very slightly different for groovy gradle files):

```kotlin
    // Pure Kotlin
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
    // Pure Java
    tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
    // Android
    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
    }
```

**More explanation:**

As the output says, the class files have a bytecode version 61, which corresponds to Java 17, and class files with a version >= 56 (Java 12), or in other words anything over Java 11, are not officially supported.

In this case the sealed classes it's talking about are likely the Java ones introduced in Java 17, rather than the Kotlin ones that will if targeting Java 11 get compiled to Java-11-compatible byte code.

Comment: But latest gradel 8.0 requires java version 17

Comment: I encountered the same error but my gradlePluginVersion  is "7.3.1" (com.android.tools.build:gradle). And I am using java 11.0.20 to build the app. Do you know why?

Answer (score 24):

After upgrading to AGP 8.0 a few issues including this one came up, here's how to resolve each one.

#### Resolving Sealed Class

As of Aug 16th 2023 you can use the following block of code in your `settings.gradle` or `settings.gradle.kts` files until the release of Android Studio Hedgehog / AGP 8.2

```
pluginManagement {
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.2.24")
    }
}
```

source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227160052#comment37

#### Resolving java.lang.StringConcatFactory

add this rule to your `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
```

source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250197571#comment25

#### Missing Classes

See this answer for resolving the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/76201356/1269953

Comment: I encountered the same error but my gradlePluginVersion is "7.3.1" (com.android.tools.build:gradle). And I am using java 11.0.20 to build the app. Do you know why? –

Answer (score 17):

Add this to gradle solve my issue

```
pluginManagement {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                // r8 maven
                url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            // r8 version
            classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.2.16-dev")
        }
    }
}
```

source:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290412574

Comment: If people are confused where to add it, add it in settings gradle file of root project

Answer (score 5):

Sealed classes are not fully supported in the D8 and R8 compilers (the compilers producing your `Sealed classes are not supported as program classes` error). Fully supporting sealed classes is tracked in https://issuetracker.google.com/227160052. The D8 support will be present in Android Studio Electric Eel, [currently in preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) whereas the R8 support will no be there until a later version.

Answer (score 4):

Just upgrade Gradle to at least 7.4.0

Comment: This solved my issue, I was using 7.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying gradle file as below and adding proguard rules written in "missing_rules" files solved the issue for us!

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(11)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I did the following:

**build.gradle.kt (:app module)**

```kotlin
android {
    // ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}
```

**gradle.properties (project)**

```
org.gradle.java.installations.fromEnv=JDK17
```

**Environment**

- Android Studio Giraffe: 2022.3.1 RC 1
- Kotlin: 1.8.21
- Android Gradle Plugin: 8.1.0-rc01
- JDK version: 17
- CompileSdk: 33
- Variables: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/data/android-sdk JAVA_HOME=/data/jdk/jdk-17 JDK17=/data/jdk/jdk-17

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Android Studio Giraffe patch 2 when a library module that was consumed by the app module was obfuscated by accident.

As soon as I turned off the obfuscation on the library module all the sudden the app module was obfuscated without any issues.

Note: project was set up for Java 17, including the library module.