work manager package not working in flutter project
I import package from pub.dev
workmanager: ^0.5.2
then I run my project and I get this error
` A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)`

So I change my kotlin version in setting.gradle file as below
before
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

after
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.10" apply false
}

after this I getting below Error
ERROR:D:\demo\build\workmanager\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: com.android.tools.r8.internal.Hc: Sealed classes are not supported as program classes
to solve this error I follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73453524/ after this I get another error is
 Could not find method dependencies() for arguments [settings_6h1jfprapbazntevniwzdshu9$_run_closure1$_closure5@4011c54d] on object of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginManagementSpec.
setting.gradle file
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools:r8:8.2.24")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.10" apply false
}

include ":app"


Android Studio Version: Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 2
Android Gradle version: 7.6.3
JDK version: 17.0.10
CompileSdk: 34

I hope I will get a solution. Thank you.
